# Text Processing...print the 1st occurrence of pattern1 and 8th and 9th occurrence of pattern 2

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a text file and I want to print the 1st line starting with pattern "abcd" and also the 8th and 9th lines which are started with "DDD" pattern. Any sed or awk for doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
awk '/^abcd/{p++;if(p==1) print}/^DDD/{q++;if(q==8||q==9)print}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne 'push @{ $h->{$1} }, $_ if /.*(abcd|DDD).*/;END{print join "\n", @{ $h->{abcd}}[0]; print join "\n", @{ $h->{DDD}}[7..8];}' file
```

or decomposed :

```
perl -lne '
    push @{ $h->{$1} }, $_ if /.*(abcd|DDD).*/;
    END{
        print join "\n", @{ $h->{abcd} }[0], @{ $h->{DDD} }[7..8];
    }
' file
```